# Getting idToken 'null' when using google_sign_in in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am using google_sign_in plug in.

It is working good. but I have a problem.

I need to send idToken to backend server to verify a user.

But IdToken is null from google sign in response.

code is simple

```
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
      await googleUser.authentication;
  print("Printing google user info");
  print(googleAuth.accessToken);
  print(googleAuth.idToken);
  print(googleUser.displayName);
```

Other properties have a correct value. but idToken is null

I googled for this and says that I need to web client id.

So I did

`final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(clientId: webClientId);`

Can you guys help?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: the clientId param is not available for Android. It's mainly used for iOS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Edit 27/12/2023

### use flutter Cli

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

---

I faced with this Problem for two days and finally. (in my case) this solution works.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android#installing-your-firebase-configuration-file

- adding `com.google.gms:google-services` as a dependency inside of the `android/build.gradle`

  ```
    dependencies {
      // ... other dependencies
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
  }
  ```
- adding `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in `/android/app/build.gradle`

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  ```

Comment: This did not fix it for me, I've already had these dependencies set and still ran into this error

Comment: This did not work for me too. given web link invaild

Answer (score 7):

Hi after a long time i although found a solution.

In short there was a problem with the Firebase setup, which doesn't occure because i used:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: 
defaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

Which makes my code work but hide the real failure, which occurs when i just use:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

But actually the first approach is the better one but long story short.

There is something wrong with the firebase sdk setup. Follow this official tutorial for setup first: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Now i did not worked. But if i changed the build.gradle (root / project) from:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false
}
```

to

```
plugins {
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}
```

it worked.
Does this make sense?
For me not.
Am i happy that it works now?
Yes :)

Comment: 4.4.0 -> not work.
4.3.15 -> works.

why?

Comment: Wow this was the only solution that worked for me. I have no idea why 4.4.0 doesn't work for flutter. I recently updated to flutter 3.19 and it requires gradle updates due to errors. Google sign in stopped working after but I never thought this was the problem.

Comment: Did anyone found why latest does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to authenticate the user you have to specify the scopes like this

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
            scopes: [
                'email',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
            ],
        );
```

then you can request the user to authenticate.
to get the isToken call this method

```
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await result.authentication;
```

if yu have correctly configurate the project in the cloud console you should get the id with no problem

Comment: You are correct that you must do that. But that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: thanks, this will fix the issue but only few times I'm getting null on this

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solutions:

1. Since I generate my `google-service.json` from flutterfire CLI, my first `google-service.json` has empty array of `oauth_client`.
2. Then I added my Android SHA1 fingerprint in my Firebase Project Settings. After that I checked on https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials, the OAuth 2.0 is added for my Android Client with SHA1 autofilled there
3. Here is the crucial part, re-generate your `google-service.json` from Firebase Project Settings (since your OAuth 2.0 just added on point #2, but your `google-service.json` is generated on point #1). Recheck your `google-service.json`, the `oauth_client` key inside should be filled with some OAuth 2.0 that you just added on point #2

Answer (score 1):

As I got the solution in Flutter today:

I've passed the GoogleSignIn Parameters as below:

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  clientId:
      '750800371744-xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);
```

This is how you'll get the client id:

[image]

And used that as below:

```
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
    await googleSignIn.signIn();

if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
  log(googleSignInAccount.toString());

  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  user = User(googleSignInAccount.displayName ?? '',
      googleSignInAccount.email ?? '', googleSignInAccount.photoUrl ?? '');

  log("Acccess Token : ${googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken}");
  log("idToken : ${googleSignInAuthentication.idToken}");
}
```

And I got both the token successfully. Hope it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I delete the google sign in provider from the firebase project, (delete it entirely instead of disabling it) and delete all unused oauth 2.0 services, including the web application, then re-enable the google sign in provider and re-init firebase project using flutter-fire and it should work

Comment: Now in 2024 I have the same problem and this solution + all other solutions didn't work for me :)