# Does Test user dont get id_token from google sigh in in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-signin

```
final result = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
final ggAuth = await result?.authentication;
print(ggAuth!.idToken);
print(ggAuth.accessToken);
```

and but i m not getting idToken in response from google
what m i missing?

![Image]([so here we can see there is no idToken from google sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjV6l.png) )

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issue using google_sign_in on an Android project.
and I found this on [stackoverflow]( which might helped, but in my case, it's not working.

[Getting idToken 'null' when using google_sign_in in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63891637/getting-idtoken-null-when-using-google-sign-in-in-flutter)

after searching for a while, I found [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20903#issuecomment-1433172720) help.

1. Create an empty Web OAuth Token in the Google Cloud Console.
2. Paste
   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources> <string name="default_web_client_id">your client goes here</string> </resources>`
   inside android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml (create one if you don't have it)
3. Add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'` in in android/app/build.gradle, under the dependencies.

[a link for my notion note with pictures (but it's in chinese)](https://placid-detail-540.notion.site/google_sign_in-idToken-null-cc531fc1c35f4eb5a5d0fa10fc7729f8)

Comment: for anyone searching, this seems to do the job, even though its looks as a really weird solution